# `lift` a type into a Template Haskell `TypeQ`

Tags: haskell, metaprogramming, template-haskell

If I have a value (of a type that is an instance of the [`Lift` typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.16.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#t:Lift)), I can use `lift` to create a Template Haskell representation of a term that evaluates to that value.

Is there anything similar for types? To give a small example, suppose I wanted to write

```
foo :: (SomeAppropriateConstraintOn a) => proxy a -> ExpQ
foo pa = [| \x -> (x :: $(liftType pa)) |]
```

How would I write this function?

One idea, alluded to in [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/8tak3p/convert_a_proxy_to_a_type_with_template_haskell/), is to use the `TypeRep` of `a`. However, this isn't as simple as that thread makes it sound. Here's what I tried: a function that turns `TypeRep a` into a Template Haskell `Type` by recursively wrapping its tycon names in `ConT`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}

import Type.Reflection
import Language.Haskell.TH as TH

liftTypeRep :: TypeRep a -> TH.Type
liftTypeRep ty = foldl AppT t0 [liftTypeRep ty' | SomeTypeRep ty' <- args]
  where
    (con, args) = splitApps ty
    t0 = ConT $ mkName (tyConModule con <> "." <> tyConName con)
```

But this (unsurprisingly) fails for data kinds. To illustrate, let's make a simple `Nat`-indexed data type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, KindSignatures #-}

import GHC.TypeLits

data Foo (n :: Nat) where
    MkFoo :: Foo n
```

Now if I try to `liftTypeRep` the `TypeRep` of `Foo 42`, I get a nonsensical type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, QuasiQuotes #-}

import Type.Reflection

test = $([| MkFoo :: $(pure $ liftTypeRep (typeRep :: TypeRep (Foo 42))) |])
```

The error message is:

```
liftTypeRep.hs:8:10: error:
    • Illegal type constructor or class name: ‘42’
      When splicing a TH expression:
        Foo.MkFoo :: Foo.Foo (GHC.TypeLits.42)
    • In the untyped splice:
        $([| MkFoo ::
               $(pure $ liftTypeRep (typeRep :: TypeRep (Foo 42))) |])
  |
8 | test = $([| MkFoo :: $(pure $ liftTypeRep (typeRep :: TypeRep (Foo 42))) |])
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If we print the splice, it is obviously wrong:

```
SigE (ConE Foo.MkFoo) (AppT (ConT Foo.Foo) (ConT GHC.TypeLits.42))
```

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/8tak3p/convert_a_proxy_to_a_type_with_template_haskell/ ?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I don't think there's enough detail there. The idea of starting from a `TypeRep a` is a good one, but it isn't as simple as folding `AppT` over `splitApps`: https://gist.github.com/gergoerdi/3a956ec99da5e6ae73d2d15a0300ab2b but this one chokes on type-level literals, e.g. [`Index`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/clash-prelude-1.2.5/docs/Clash-Sized-Index.html#t:Index) `8192`

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. well it's no surprise that `ConT "TypeLits.42"` is not a good representation, since that is exactly what TH's `LitT` constructor is for.

Comment: Yes but how do you know when to use `ConT` and when `LitT`? If it's an integer you can `show` it and parse it...

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. well yeah, exactly. Hence the question.

Comment: Hmm maybe with `typeRepKind`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone else asked this, and I ended up writing [`lift-type`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lift-type) to fill this need.

It ends up being a bit hairy, since we need to parse out what sort of type it is from the type string. The easy case works for most types - regular type constructors, functions, even promoted data constructors (eg `'True`). I wrote some tests in the library that mostly cover the use case.

The code is here:

```hs
liftType :: forall t. Typeable t => Type
liftType =
    go (typeRep @t)
  where
    go :: forall k (a :: k). TypeRep a -> Type
    go tr =
        case tr of
            Con tyCon ->
                mk tyCon
            App trA trB ->
                AppT (go trA) (go trB)
            Fun trA trB ->
                ConT ''(->) `AppT` go trA `AppT` go trB

    mk :: TyCon -> Type
    mk tyCon =
        let
            tcName =
                tyConName tyCon
        in
            if hasTick tcName
            then
                let
                    nameBase =
                        mkOccName (drop 1 tcName)
                    name =
                        Name nameBase flavor
                in
                    PromotedT name
            else if hasDigit tcName then
                LitT (NumTyLit (read tcName))
            else if hasQuote tcName then
                LitT (StrTyLit (stripQuotes tcName))
            else
                let
                    nameBase =
                        mkOccName tcName
                    flavor =
                        NameG
                            TcClsName
                            (mkPkgName $ tyConPackage tyCon)
                            (mkModName $ tyConModule tyCon)
                    name =
                        Name nameBase flavor
                in
                    ConT name

    stripQuotes xs =
        case xs of
            [] ->
                []
            ('"' : rest) ->
                reverse (stripQuotes (reverse rest))
            _ ->
                xs
    hasTick = prefixSatisfying ('\'' ==)
    hasDigit = prefixSatisfying isDigit
    hasQuote = prefixSatisfying ('"' ==)
    isList = ("'[]" ==)
    prefixSatisfying :: (Char -> Bool) -> [Char] -> Bool
    prefixSatisfying p xs =
        case xs of
            a : _ ->
                p a
            _ ->
                False
```

FOr full imports and extensions, see the source on Hackage.

Comment: Shouldn't it be called `Language.Haskell.TH.LiftType`?

Comment: I prefer shorter module names where possible.